# Javascript always failing

Tags: javascript, office-365, client-object-model

I am busy writing some javascript to take a list of selected documents and do some processing on a list with each document in Office365. I am getting a strange error when the code tries to load the document from the absolute URL. The document is guaranteed to be in the same `SP.Web` that the JS is in.

The error is

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

Below is the JS I have:

```
function GetFile(attachment, item) {
   var fileContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

   var site = fileContext.get_site();
   fileContext.load(site);

   fileContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
       var relUrl = attachment.Url.replace(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl, '');

       var file = fileContext.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(relUrl);

       fileContext.load(file, 'ListItemAllFields');

       fileContext.executeQueryAsync(
           function () {
               var listItem = file.get_listItemAllFields(); 
           },
           function (sender, args) {
               console.log(args.get_message()); //errorhandling
           }
       );
   }, function(sender, args) {
       console.log(args.get_message());
   });  
}
```

This is not a permissions thing as I can take the url of the documents being selected and open them fine from the browser.

I have noticed, that I can't seem to hit the `client.svc` service on the site in question when taking the url for the request from the request object.

Comment: What is attachment parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The error `Value does not fall within the expected range` usually occurs when the file specified via `serverRelativeUrl` parameter in [SP.Web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246729(v=office.15).aspx)  does not exists, so make sure the url has the following format:

```
/<site>/<list url>/Attachments/<item id>/<attachment name>
```

I guess (since it is not clear from question) `attachment.Url` stores the location of [AttachmentFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.attachment(v=office.15).aspx). In that case SP.File.listItemAllFields property will be **empty** since *attachment file is not associated with list item*.

Comment: The naming seems to be miss-leading here. Attachment.Url is a URL to a file stored in a library within the same site, these are not attachments in a list. What I am looking to do is create a new list item and attached the selected files to the item.

Comment: I would recommend you in future to specify a complete code examples in order to avoid this type of miss-leading, because from your question we could only guess what attachment variable means..

Answer (score 0):

You suggestion of the "file doesn't exist" led me down the right road. The url I was using to grab the file was kissings /sites/ which was getting removed by the following:

```
var relUrl = attachment.Url.replace(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl, '');
```

I have made some changes to it and it now loads the file as expected.